# What exactly are the tags [ebinary-star] and [tbinary-star]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

[This question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/16744/revisions) was recently edited to include a tag called [tbinary-star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tbinary-star), while the original [binary-star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-star) was removed. [Another question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/27143/revisions) had its [binary-star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-star) replaced by a tag called [ebinary-star](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebinary-star). What exactly are the purpose of these tags, and do we *really* need them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect tbinary was a typo for ebinary, and I think they are referring to eclipsing binaries. I think both tags should be replaced with [eclipsing-star-systems](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipsing-star-systems).

Comment: Should we go ahead and remove them?

Comment: @fasterthanlight No, since I'm not certain I want to give more time for feedback.

Comment: The tag [eclipsing-star-systems] already exists

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for the heads up! I'll merge into that instead.

Comment: these both really look like typos by relatively inexperienced users. tbinary-star could be $T_{\text{binary star}}$ but even so that would not be a good tag. I think it's pretty safe to send them to the cornfield to join the rest of the erroneous tags.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Merges complete!